# jQuery UI Tabs force delay before changing tab on mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using the jQuery UI Tabs 1.7.2  with jQuery 1.4.2, is there a way to make it so that when you mouseover a tab, there is a delay before the tab switches?

I've been looking into using the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin to do this, but cannot figure out how it would fit in.

Right now my code looks like:

```
var tabs = $('.tabs').tabs({
 event: 'mouseover'
});
```

I've tried playing around with a callback on the show event, but I think I'm doing it wrong or not clear on when the callback happens:

```
$( ".tabs" ).tabs({
 show: function(event, ui) 
 { 
  setTimeout("FUNCTION_TO_CHANGE_TAB?", 200);
 }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on 1.4.2 you can use a custom event and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to do this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  event: 'mousedelay'
}).delegate('ul.ui-tabs-nav li a', 'mouseover', function() {
  clearTimeout($(this).closest('.ui-tabs').data('timeout'));
  $(this).closest('.ui-tabs').data('timeout', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    $(this).trigger('mousedelay');
  }, this), 500));
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/CAPxD/)

This works by setting the [`event` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-event) to listen for our custom event, `mousedelay`.  Then in [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), we're listening for the `mouseover` event on the anchors, clearing a timeout if there is one (we hovered over 2 tabs rapidly), and setting another.  When that timeout finishes all we're doing is triggering the `mousedelay` event on that anchor (the tab).

The [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) piece is just a short way to have `this` reference to the anchor we moused-over, not `window` (since [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) runs in a global context) when it executes.

Comment: Wow: 10.5 years on and this was the solution for me!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own event, override the mouseover and trigger a new event.

I found a blog [post about it here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-jquery-ui-tabs/#more_tabs=2)