# need delay() while hiding prev tab of jquery UI tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery UI tabs in my layout. 
Is there any way to set some delay() in hiding the previous tab when I click on next tab?

It could be very simple but got stuck here .. :(

Regards,
Era

Comment: Maybe this link can help you or provide you a little guide about how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495846/jquery-ui-tabs-force-delay-before-changing-tab-on-mouseover

Comment: Fran's link has the right idea... I just tried coming up with another solution http://jsfiddle.net/hUS9e/ but double clicking bypasses it.